# C# Event not working for different Solutions

Tags: c#, events

I have a solution with 3 projects; 1 Class Library project, 2 WinForms projects.

Lets say the 2 WinForms are (VendorUI) and (CustomerUI), (DemoLibrary) is the class library.

Class Library code:

```
namespace DemoLibrary
{
    public delegate void Notify();

    public static class Catalogue
    {
        public static event Notify NewProduct;

        public static void AddNewProduct()
        {
            if (NewProduct != null)
                NewProduct.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

VendorUI code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DemoLibrary;

namespace VendorUI
{
    public partial class Vendor : Form
    {
        public Vendor()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Catalogue.AddNewProduct();
        }
    }
}
```

CustomerUI code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using DemoLibrary;
using OtherWinFormUI;

namespace CustomerUI
{

    public partial class Customer : Form
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Catalogue.NewProduct += Catalogue_NewProduct;
        }

        void Catalogue_NewProduct()
        {
            label1.Text += string.Format("A new product is added to the catalogue ({0})\n", DateTime.Now);
        }

    }

    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [System.STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            (new OtherWinFormUI.Vendor()).Show();
            Application.Run(new Customer());
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working perfectly, until I separated each project to a different solution then ran CustomerUI and VendorUI separately, the event no longer works and the CustomerUI don't get notified when the VendorUI adds new product, I make sure the reference are ok but still the event is not firing.

Whay have I done wrong when I separated the projects ?

Comment: How are you running the projects?

Comment: If you have 2 separate running processes, they can't use events to communicate. You have to use other ways: HTTP, GRPC, sockets, message brokers, etc.

Comment: @dcg I running 2 instance of VS and running the CustomerUI and VendorUI, I press the button on the vendorUI to generate the event and the CustomerUI should update the form with a message of the event. Its working if the projects are in the same solution but separated is not. But its seems it has nothing to do with the code as 'Vladimir Serykh' mentioned above. But I am unaware of those things and how to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your separate projects are running in different processes, subscribing to events by referencing the other libraries won't actually yield anything, as the event isn't actually being fired within the process that's looking for them.

You can use a workaround such as [ManagedSpy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx) to subscribe to events from other processes, or use some [Win32 magic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to hook into the other process' messaging loop.